# Laravel Sanctum returning 401 when trying to get the authenticated user

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, axios, single-page-application

I want to get the ***currently logged in*** user whenever my React SPA starts, so I can show the user's information, but every time I try to get it from my Laravel back-end I get a 401.

I am using Laravel + Sanctum for my API, and using React in a different project for the front-end.

**BACK-END:**

I have the following in my **AuthController** controller:

```
public function user()
    {
        return auth()->user();
    }
```

Inside my routes **api.php** I have the following route:

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function () {
        Route::get('/user', [AuthController::class, 'user']);
        Route::post('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
    });
```

My **.env** file contains the following:

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:3000
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
```

**FRONT-END:**

I have a context that has the following:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    apiClient()
      .get("/api/user")
      .then((res) => {
        setUser(res.data.user);
      });
  }, []);
```

and if you are wondering, my **apiClient()** comes from here:

```
import axios from "axios";

const apiClient = () => {
  const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:8000",
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
    },
  });

  return api;
};

export default apiClient;
```

This context is at the top level of the application.

I am not sure what's going on, my route **/login** is working as expected, I send the request and receive the user information as response which I set to a React state. On page refresh this state is removed because that's how Javascript works.  I want to set it again using the **useEffect** mentioned above, so when the user loads the web app after closing the browser they can still see their information.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To authenticate your SPA, your SPA's "login" page should first make a request to the /sanctum/csrf-cookie endpoint to initialize CSRF protection for the application:

```
axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
    //Login...
});
```

For more information check https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#spa-authentication